# When is security applied to a query

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-execution-plan

If I try to get the execution plan for a query that includes a column I don't have permission to read I get a security error on the column.  This, despite the fact that I'm not actually asking to read any data, I only want the plan and I do have authority to read plans (in this case, view server state).
If the plan is in the plan cache already I have no trouble seeing it so it leaves me wondering in what order steps actually occur.

IOW if the query needs to be parsed so security can be checked even if a valid plan is already cached it severely limits the benefit of the plan cache for queries that are large because they contain lots of literal values but execute very simple plans.  If security checks can occur based on an existing plan the cache becomes far more valuable since it saves more than just optimization time.

The hypothetical scenarios below all have the same result but vastly different performance characteristics in queries where parsing can take significant time for example if a virtual table is literally included in the query text.  Does anyone know what 'really' happens?

Hash query - Check plan cache - Return found - check security - execute

Hash query - Check plan cache - Parse query- check security - optimize and cache plan - execute

Parse query - check security - Hash query - Check plan cache - Return found - execute

Parse query - check security - Hash query - Check plan cache - optimize and cache plan - execute